# Search engine considerations for wordpress content

Tags: php, wordpress, search, post

I am a web development beginner making a website in wordpress. I have been learning/using any and all web dev languages in my site as necessary.

For my site, I am planning on creating custom post types so that users can upload and manage specific kinds of content. I have a question though, with regard to wordpress posts or content and search engines.

Initially, I was thinking that I would create a general page template designed to display a specific post type. Then, when the user would click a link or what have you, the page would load the specific post into the template dynamically. So, for example, I would have a baseball team page that could display information for any baseball team. Then, if a user clicked a Yankees symbol he would be taken to that general page, populated with Yankees information.

However, recently, I have been thinking that this approach could hurt me when users search "Yankees" in google for example. Since my page is not devoted to Yankees and does not have the appropriate Yankees tags or whatever Google is looking for (because it is general), google would not list it in its results.

Should I create a page for every specific post? Is there such a thing as a custom page type?

I realize that this question may be naive or simplistic, sorry about that. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post types are a great way to separate content. However, if you are just learning Wordpress, keep in mind that categories can be pretty powerful as well and come 'built in'. Could be an easier way to learn the WordPress Codex basics, and you can build into CPT from there.

That being said, CPT behave just like 'Posts' do in a standard install of WP. So, yes, you can create specific templates for CPT singles and archives: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

In your example, you would create a CPT of 'baseball', then `archive-baseball.php`, `single-baseball.php`. Then you would want to create a post for each team inside of your 'baseball' CPT.

For SEO, the easiest thing you can do is set your permalinks to be using %postname% somewhere in the path. Done right, this will let you have a path of site.com/baseball/yankees in your sitemap. http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

I'm also a big fan of the Yoast SEO Plugin. Makes it easy to set up a lot of stuff and automatically submit updates to search engines. https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do the archive and single php files do? Are they templates for pages? Don't I suffer for not having an actual page for each team just a general template/

Comment: Yes, they are just like the base archive and single template pages for your theme, but WP calls them for the content attached to your CPT. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy When you say 'suffer'- do you mean for SEO? The answer is no, as the content gets structured similar to pages, and a good SEO plugin like Yoast will help, too. WP is a pretty good CMS as far as that goes. tk111 had a good suggestion to look at this https://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/

Comment: How do I add elements to a custom post type? Like for example, I want a post type A to have an element that houses a picture, an element that houses a "thread-style-post" (i.e. one in which the user can embed pictures and videos). I mean in standard OOP, I would just declare them as fields. Do I declare them as meta information or do I declare fields in my register_post_type function. Thanks for the time.

Comment: bob - if this question is satisfied, best to select an answer and post a second question rather than have an extended conversation in the comments. But the short answer is there are multiple ways to do it - featured images, custom fields, adding meta boxes in different parts of the admin areas. If you are just getting started, I really would just start by searching the codex (links above), look at sample code, hacking on it and then post some code. I'm happy to look when you have some code to review.

Answer (score 1):

I guess new page for post is good; with well formed url, description, keywords and sitemap your blog is seo ready.
Wordpress seo tips may be helpful for u: https://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, then how would I do this? I don't think there is such a thing as a custom page type. Do I have to manually make a page for every post or what?

Comment: Hm the best option i'm thinking about is to create custom post type manually, like wordpress doc says: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types; you are flexible with doing seo optimization then. Another option is to use ready plugin, e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/